# Confusion in output of c code

Tags: c

Can somebody please give me the explanation of the code below. the output is as mentioned after the code.

```
char s[] = "char s[] = %c%s%c; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }";

void main(){
    printf(s,34,s,34);
}
```

**OUTPUT-**

```
char s[] = "char s[] = %c%s%c; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }"; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }
```

Comment: It's simply a self replicating program. Is there that much to explain?

Comment: Using `printf()` without a prototype in scope is Undefined Behaviour ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the string `char s[] = %c%s%c; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }` as the formatting string.

The first arg is formatted with `%c`. The argument is `34`. So it prints out the ASCII character whose value is `34`, which is `"` (one character; double quotation mark).

The second arg is formatted with `%s`. The argument is that same format string, `char s[] = %c%s%c; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }`. So it prints out that same string.

The third arg is `%c`, also `34`, so it prints another quotation mark.

That's all there is to it. In parts:

```
lit --> char s[] = 
%c  --> "
%s  --> char s[] = %c%s%c; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }
%c  --> "
lit --> ; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }
```

Which, when put together, is:

```
char s[] = "char s[] = %c%s%c; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }"; main(){ printf(s,43,s,43); }
```

Comment: Note the quine appears to be broken, since it prints out a version with `43` rather than `34`.

Comment: it's more a failed attempt at a quine than a quine. but the poster didn't ask anything relating to a quine anyway

Comment: The return type of `main` is also missing from the output.

Comment: Why the edit? `34` does not represent `'"'`, it represents `"`.

Comment: @Claudiu we're talking about character literals, so I made it a character literal. It was for consistency with the fact you used `"` around the format string because it was a string literal.

Comment: oh gotcha, thanks. i think i'll take out the `"`s around the other ones